# How to programmatically calculate all cache size of installed application?

Tags: android, caching, memory-management

i just want to show list of all installed application name with cache size. Cache size must be same as native setting application show in android device.

i able to list all installed application pkg name but can't calculate same cache size which native setting application show(i m talking about that place where clear cache option in setting).

```
pkNames = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

                    ArrayAdapter<PackageInfo> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<PackageInfo>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pkNames);
                     final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                    for(int i =0;i<pkNames.size();i++)
                    {
                        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(pkNames.get(i).packageName.toString(), 0);
                        File file = new File(applicationInfo.publicSourceDir);
                        long size = file.length();
                        System.out.println("application name == "+pkNames.get(i).packageName.toString()+"  ,and size of cache is == "+size(this, size));
                    }
```

I use this code but it will give me .apk size of that application. :(
Please help 
thanks in advance.

Comment: i checked but cant understand ur answer

Comment: have u tried the code ? as its working for me.. it is calculating cache size of the installed apps ...

Comment: yes but in activity where is "IDataStatus" class  also where is "IPackageStatsObserver.class"  what  is IPackageStatsObserver.Stub which u try to extend. Should i include any lib in this project

Comment: no it wont required any library or anything ... by adding IPackageStatsObserver.aidl file to the mentioned package it should work

Comment: yes dude.............

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the cache size of the Installed Application directly u can not get. 
As using [PackageManger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)  we cant directly get the details regarding installed package size as abstract [getPackageSizeInfo](http://goo.gl/FmV49A) method is directly not accessible so by using [**Java Reflection**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html) you can invoke it.It may not work if in future the method name change or any thing changed.

You need to create AIDL [IPackageStatsObserver](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/content/pm/IPackageStatsObserver.java#IPackageStatsObserver).aidl & [PackageStats.aidl](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/content/pm/PackageStats.java#PackageStats) which should be in the `android.content.pm` package as you cant directly access them.

**IPackageStatsObserver.aidl**

```
package android.content.pm;
import android.content.pm.PackageStats;
oneway interface IPackageStatsObserver {
void onGetStatsCompleted(in android.content.pm.PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded);
}
```

**PackageStats.aidl**

```
package android.content.pm;
parcelable PackageStats;
```

IPackageStatsObserver.aidl & PackageStats.aidl both keep it in `android.content.pm` package.
**IDataStatus**

```
public interface IDataStatus {
    public void onStatusListner(String msg);
}
```

**Activity**

```
    public class MyScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    public static final int FETCH_PACKAGE_SIZE_COMPLETED = 100;
    public static final int ALL_PACAGE_SIZE_COMPLETED = 200;
    IDataStatus onIDataStatus;
    TextView lbl_cache_size;
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        findViewById(R.id.btn_get_cacheSize).setOnClickListener(this);
        lbl_cache_size = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_cache_size);
        // clearCache();
    }

    private void showProgress(String message) {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        pd.setTitle("Please Wait...");
        pd.setMessage(message);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();

    }

    long packageSize = 0, size = 0;
    AppDetails cAppDetails;
    public ArrayList<PackageInfoStruct> res;

    private void getpackageSize() {
        cAppDetails = new AppDetails(this);
        res = cAppDetails.getPackages();
        if (res == null)
            return;
        for (int m = 0; m < res.size(); m++) {
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            Method getPackageSizeInfo;
            try {
                getPackageSizeInfo = pm.getClass().getMethod(
                        "getPackageSizeInfo", String.class,
                        IPackageStatsObserver.class);
                getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(pm, res.get(m).pname,
                        new cachePackState());
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        handle.sendEmptyMessage(ALL_PACAGE_SIZE_COMPLETED);
        Log.v("Total Cache Size", " " + packageSize);

    }

    private Handler handle = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case FETCH_PACKAGE_SIZE_COMPLETED:
                if (packageSize > 0)
                    size = (packageSize / 1024000);
                lbl_cache_size.setText("Cache Size : " + size + " MB");
                break;
            case ALL_PACAGE_SIZE_COMPLETED:
                if (null != pd)
                    if (pd.isShowing())
                        pd.dismiss();

                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }

    };

    private class cachePackState extends IPackageStatsObserver.Stub {

        @Override
        public void onGetStatsCompleted(PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)
                throws RemoteException {
            Log.d("Package Size", pStats.packageName + "");
            Log.i("Cache Size", pStats.cacheSize + "");
            Log.w("Data Size", pStats.dataSize + "");
            packageSize = packageSize + pStats.cacheSize;
            Log.v("Total Cache Size", " " + packageSize);
            handle.sendEmptyMessage(FETCH_PACKAGE_SIZE_COMPLETED);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_get_cacheSize:
            size = 0;
            packageSize = 0;
            showProgress("Calculating Cache Size..!!!");
            /**
             * You can also use async task
             * */
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getpackageSize();
                }
            }).start();

            break;
        }
    }

}
```

**AppDetails**

```
public class AppDetails {
    Activity mActivity;
    public ArrayList<PackageInfoStruct> res = new ArrayList<PackageInfoStruct>();
    public ListView list;
    public String app_labels[];

    public AppDetails(Activity mActivity) {
        this.mActivity = mActivity;

    }

    public ArrayList<PackageInfoStruct> getPackages() {
        ArrayList<PackageInfoStruct> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /*
                                                                     * false =
                                                                     * no system
                                                                     * packages
                                                                     */
        final int max = apps.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            apps.get(i);
        }
        return apps;
    }

    private ArrayList<PackageInfoStruct> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {

        List<PackageInfo> packs = mActivity.getPackageManager()
                .getInstalledPackages(0);
        try {
            app_labels = new String[packs.size()];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
            PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
            if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
                continue;
            }
            PackageInfoStruct newInfo = new PackageInfoStruct();
            newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(
                    mActivity.getPackageManager()).toString();
            newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
            newInfo.datadir = p.applicationInfo.dataDir;
            newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
            newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
            newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(mActivity
                    .getPackageManager());
            res.add(newInfo);

            app_labels[i] = newInfo.appname;
        }
        return res;
    }

    class PackageInfoStruct {
        String appname = "";
        String pname = "";
        String versionName = "";
        int versionCode = 0;
        Drawable icon;
        String datadir = "";
    }
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_get_cacheSize"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get Cache Size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_cache_size"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cache Size : " />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes...but i want to know the status of cache background process...How can i achieve this....

Comment: Actually i want to know the application background cached process and size of process which they used.

Comment: IDataStatus is an aidl file or a simple interface

Comment: @Nepster its a simple interface

Comment: @Nepster for the aidl i hve mentioned file name with extension .aidl

Comment: @user1140237 Do I have to put these aidl files in `android.content.pm` package under src folder???

Comment: where should be  IPackageStatsObserver.aidl & PackageStats.aidl files?

Comment: "Do I have to put these aidl files in android.content.pm package under src folder??? –  Vivek Warde 15 hours ago"... Yes tht package should be in src folder . check the answer **IPackageStatsObserver.aidl & PackageStats.aidl both keep it in android.content.pm package.**

Comment: How can i delete all cache in my application?

Comment: @Arun Yes its also possible. i guess this question is regarding how to get cache size so for the deleting related you need to ask separate question

Comment: getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getPackageSizeInfo  exception.

Comment: @VishalChaudhari in which version of android  ?

Comment: hi I am getting exception in android 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

Locate the application cache folder into memory in following path

"/data/data/com.your.package.appname/cache"

Calculate the application cache size on the disk.