# Clearing all application cache in android

Tags: android, caching

I got all application cache sizes using this link [How to programmatically calculate all cache size of installed application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407799/how-to-programmatically-calculate-all-cache-size-of-installed-application). Now I need to clear all cache data. So please tell me how to clear all application cache memory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clear cache for all application installed on mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619209/clear-cache-for-all-application-installed-on-mobile)

Answer (score 0):

try with following code.

```
PackageManager  pm = getPackageManager();
// Get all methods on the PackageManager
Method[] methods = pm.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method m : methods) {
    if (m.getName().equals("freeStorage")) {
        // Found the method I want to use
        try {
            long desiredFreeStorage = 8 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // Request for 8GB of free space
            m.invoke(pm, desiredFreeStorage , null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Method invocation failed. Could be a permission problem
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

You will need to have this in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"/>
```

I hope it will work