# Get Cached data storage programmatically

Tags: android, caching

I want to get cached data size at "Internal storage" in "settings", like this:

[image: Cache Data size]

I tried to get all application cache by invoking **getPackageSizeInfo** using Java Reflection. Yes it did got all cached size of apps, but the size is smaller than the cached data size in "settings" above. This is the picture when I used this method:

[image: get cached data]

in settings, the cached data size 840 MB, but when in my app is 493 MB.

These are my codes

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static final int FETCH_PACKAGE_SIZE_COMPLETED = 100;
    public static final int ALL_PACKAGE_SIZE_COMPLETED = 200;
    IDataStatus onIDataStatus;
    TextView lbl_cache_size;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    long packageSize = 0, size = 0, dataSize = 0, data = 0;
    AppDetails cAppDetails;
    public ArrayList<AppDetails.PackageInfoStruct> res;
    int totalSize;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.btn_get_cacheSize).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.btn_delete_cache).setOnClickListener(this);
        lbl_cache_size = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_cache_size);


    }

    private void showProgress(String message) {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        pd.setTitle("Please wait...");
        pd.setMessage(message);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }

    private void getPackageSize() {
        cAppDetails = new AppDetails(this);
        res = cAppDetails.getPackages();
        if (res == null)
            return;
        for (int m = 0; m < res.size(); m++) {
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            Method getPackageSizeInfo;
            try {
                getPackageSizeInfo = pm.getClass().getMethod(
                        "getPackageSizeInfo", String.class,
                        IPackageStatsObserver.class);
                getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(pm, res.get(m).pname,
                        new cachePackState());
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        handle.sendEmptyMessage(ALL_PACKAGE_SIZE_COMPLETED);
        Log.v("Total Cache Size", " " + packageSize);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_get_cacheSize:
                size = 0;
                packageSize = 0;
                dataSize = 0;
                data = 0;
                showProgress("Calculating Cache Size..!!!");
                /*
                * You can also use sync task
                 */
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getPackageSize();
                    }
                }).start();

                //getPackageSize();

                break;
            case R.id.btn_delete_cache:
                deleteCache();
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
    }

    private Handler handle = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case FETCH_PACKAGE_SIZE_COMPLETED:
                    String sizeInHuman = "";
                    if (packageSize > 0) {
                       // size = (packageSize / 1024000);
                        //data = (dataSize / 1024000); //boy
                        sizeInHuman = humanReadableByteCount(packageSize, true);
                    }
                    //lbl_cache_size.setText("Cache Size : " + size + " MB and Data Size : "+ data + " MB");
                    lbl_cache_size.setText("Cache Size : " + sizeInHuman);
                    break;
                case ALL_PACKAGE_SIZE_COMPLETED:
                    if (null != pd)
                        if (pd.isShowing())
                            pd.dismiss();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    private class cachePackState extends IPackageStatsObserver.Stub {

        @Override
        public void onGetStatsCompleted(PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded) throws RemoteException {
            Log.d("Package Size", pStats.packageName + "");
            Log.i("Cache Size", pStats.cacheSize + "");
            Log.w("Data Size", pStats.dataSize + "");
            packageSize = packageSize + pStats.cacheSize;
            Log.v("Total Cache Size", " " + packageSize );
            handle.sendEmptyMessage(FETCH_PACKAGE_SIZE_COMPLETED);

        }
    }

    private void deleteCache() {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        //Get all methods on the packageManager
        Method[] methods = pm.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method m : methods) {
            if (m.getName().equals("freeStorage")) {
                //Found the method I want to use
                try {
                    m.invoke(pm, Long.MAX_VALUE, null);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static String humanReadableByteCount(long bytes, boolean si) {
        int unit = si ? 1000 : 1024;
        if (bytes < unit) return bytes + " B";
        int exp = (int) (Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(unit));
        String pre = (si ? "kMGTPE" : "KMGTPE").charAt(exp - 1) + (si ? "" : "i");
        return String.format("%.1f %sB", bytes / Math.pow(unit, exp), pre);
    }
}
```

**AppDetails**

```
public class AppDetails {

    Activity mActivity;
    public ArrayList<PackageInfoStruct> res = new ArrayList<PackageInfoStruct>();
    public ListView list;
    public String app_labels[];

    public AppDetails(Activity mActivity) {
        this.mActivity = mActivity;

    }

    public ArrayList<PackageInfoStruct> getPackages() {
        ArrayList<PackageInfoStruct> apps = getInstalledApps(true); /*
                                                                     * false =
                                                                     * no system
                                                                     * packages
                                                                     */
        final int max = apps.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            apps.get(i);
        }
        return apps;
    }

    private ArrayList<PackageInfoStruct> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {

        List<PackageInfo> packs = mActivity.getPackageManager()
                .getInstalledPackages(0);
        try {
            app_labels = new String[packs.size()];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
            PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
            //if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
             //   continue;
            //}
            PackageInfoStruct newInfo = new PackageInfoStruct();
            newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(
                    mActivity.getPackageManager()).toString();
            newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
            newInfo.datadir = p.applicationInfo.dataDir;
            newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
            newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
            newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(mActivity
                    .getPackageManager());
            res.add(newInfo);

            app_labels[i] = newInfo.appname;
        }
        return res;
    }

    class PackageInfoStruct {
        String appname = "";
        String pname = "";
        String versionName = "";
        int versionCode = 0;
        Drawable icon;
        String datadir = "";
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get cached data size in storage?

The reference: 
[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407799/how-to-programmatically-calculate-all-cache-size-of-installed-application/28408453#28408453)