# Calculated Cache size is smaller than size showing in Settings/Storage?

Tags: java, android, caching

I was trying to make a cache cleaner. Before "Cleaning" I want user to know how much cache is stored.  At first I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28408453/6697154) answer, but I noticed that it is not showing "External Storage Cache".  Then I added following code to calculate "External Storage Cache".

```
public void SearchForExternalCache(){
    File f= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Android/data");
    File ff[]=f.listFiles();
    for (File pf:ff)
        initCache(pf);
}

public static long getExternalStorageStatus(){
    StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

    long blockSize = 0;
    long totalSize=0;
    long availableSize=0;
    long freeSize=0;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        blockSize = statFs.getBlockSizeLong();
        totalSize= statFs.getBlockCountLong()*blockSize;
        availableSize = statFs.getAvailableBlocksLong()*blockSize;
        freeSize = statFs.getFreeBlocksLong()*blockSize;
    } else {
        blockSize = statFs.getBlockSize();
        totalSize= statFs.getBlockCount()*blockSize;
        availableSize = statFs.getAvailableBlocks()*blockSize;
        freeSize = statFs.getFreeBlocks()*blockSize;
    }
    return totalSize-availableSize;
}

public void initCache(File packageFile){
    File cacheFIle=new File(packageFile,"cache");
    if(cacheFIle.exists()){
        E.put(packageFile.getName(),getDirSize(cacheFIle));
        Log.e("Cache Found For",""+packageFile.getName()+" = "+(E.get(packageFile.getName())));
    }
    return;
}

public long getDirSize(File dir){
    long size = 0;
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (file != null && file.isDirectory()) {
            size += getDirSize(file);
        } else if (file != null && file.isFile()) {
            size += file.length();
        }
    }
    return size;
}
```

Then I modified the `onGetStatsCompleted` method to sum up the total, but the total is still a bit smaller than cache size showing in Settings/Storage.

Can anyone explain why or how I can achieve the same result as Settings/Storage?

Comment: From what I've heard, the available volume will never match the physical volume when it comes to memory. It is the same with a USB, it may say 2GB but in reality it's around 1.8 or 1.9GB. Some of that storage is unavailabe to you and I think the same is happening here

Comment: Thanks, but some apps like 'Power Clean' can shows a more accurate cache size. I mean more closer to the size showing at Settings/Storage. I wonder what more they do to achieve this..? moreover I was wandering about the residual junk detection feature, can you tell me how they detects those..?

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure how they do it programatically. I only knew about it at the physical level. Good luck and post here if you find an answer!
Also, check here, not sure if it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407799/how-to-programmatically-calculate-all-cache-size-of-installed-application?noredirect=1&lq=1